# Average of formatted numbers appears incorrect

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have three cells I'm averaging.

```
a1= 19.5
a2= 19.5
a3= 19.5
a4= 19.5
a5= 19.4 
a6= 19.48 <<== result of average above ^^^
```

I have a cell formula that I calculate this by doing this:

```
a6=IF(average(a1:a5) >= 19.5, "20", average(a1:a5))
```

How come I'm not getting the result "20" in cell a6? doesn't 19.48 round up to 19.5 as specified on my formula? I've changed the cell format to only have 1 decimal so the result should be 19.5. Am I missing something here?

Comment: I'm assuming that the fields showing as 19.5 are actually other numbers rounded up to 1 decimal place. what value is actually in the cell when you edit it? [![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hRU6n.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hRU6n.png)

Comment: 19.48 is the value when averaging the five numbers, I've also tried to insert a formula in cell a7 = round(a6, 1) then do a if(a7 >= 19.5, "20", a7) but still returns me the value of a6.

Comment: That's exactly the answer, though. What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The average of A1:A5 is 19.48, and 19.48 is not greater than or equal to 19.5. That is why your formula returns `20`.

You must understand that the cell value does not change due to number formatting. Formatting only changes what is shown, not the underlying value. For example, even if your cell says `19.5` in this case, if you put the formula below in a cell with general formatting, the result would be `0.48`.

```
=A6-19
```

If you want to change the underlying value, you will have to build the rounding into your formula.

```
=IF(ROUND(AVERAGE(A1:A5),1)>=19.5,"20",ROUND(AVERAGE(A1:A5),1))
```